# Prove that for every integer $f > 1$ with factorization $f = 2^g(2n-1)$ for integers $g, n$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for every integer $f > 1$ with factorization $f = 2^g(2n - 1)$ for integers $g, n$ with $g \geq 0$ and $n > 1$, the integer $2^f + 1$ is not prime. Thus, the only Fermat primes are of the form $2^f + 1$ with $f$ equal to $2^g$ for some integer $g \geq 0$.

Comment: Well, it would be divisible by $2^{2^g}+1$.

Comment: Do you want $n>1$ or $n \ge 1$?